# Custom Permalinks For CPT and pages with parent. Advanced Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I've created a CPT - `Community Post`: https://pastebin.com/9XSrvZAr

For this CPT I've created two custom taxonomies: https://pastebin.com/fNhfpiM6

1. `community_post_domain`
2. `community_post_type`

My goal is that the permalink of all single community posts will go as follows: 
https://example.com/community/%POST_DOMAIN_SLUG%/%POST_SLUG% 
So, for example, if I have a community post with the title 'Go Micro Services', and it has `community_post_domain` set to a term named `Kubernetes`, the permalink will be: 
https://example.com/community/kubernetes/go-micro-services.

This is how I do the permalink manipulation:
https://pastebin.com/aP5rEBjY

Also, I've created a static page: `Community`, that has the permalink: https://example.com/community. 
So far, so good. The problem arises when I try to publish a page and I want it to have a permalink like so: https://example.com/community/%PAGE_SLUG% 
I create the page, let's say, for example, `Hello World`. I set the parent to be the `Community` page. When I click `Publish`, the page is created, and in the WordPress dashboard I see that the page's permalink is as expected: https://example.com/community/hello-world 
BUT, and this is **the actual problem** - when I'm trying to visit the page's permalink, I get 404. 
I tried going to `Permalinks` in WP dashboard and update the permalinks, didn't help.
Any Ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that usually we will not have too many pages (5-10), the easiest and fastest method to solve this problem, without rewriting everything, is to write separate rewrite_rules for each page.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^community/hello-world/?',
    'index.php?page_id=123',
    'top'
);
```

The basis of your problem is this line

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community', 'with_front' => false ),
```

When you register a custom taxonomy, you use

```
'slug' => 'community'
```

Now wordpress thinks that in this link https://example.com/community/hello-world/

> hello-world = taxonomy slug

To diagnose such problems more accurately and see what rewrite rule is used on the current page - try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/